# gDEBugger's Texture Viewer doesn't work

Tags: opengl, textures

I wanted to look at the textures in my app, so I ran it under gDEBugger and opened the "Textures, Buffers and Images Viewer" there. But it says "No textures are available":

[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7sc1.png)

Any ideas?

This is on an Mobile Intel 4 Series videocard.

Note: gDEBugger required me to copy an opengl32.dll file from its "spies" dir to my app's dir. Otherwise my app wouldn't work under gDEBugger at all.

Comment: I think this is a problem with Intel drivers (which generally suck). Have you tried a software OGL backend?

Comment: @dark_charlie: Any easy way to enable such a backend?

Comment: See http://www.mesa3d.org/, they have a documentation on how to use it as a backend to your application. It should work fine with gDebugger.